# Comparison of android.provider.CallLog.Date fails

Tags: android

When I do below code without that comparison it works, but with that comparison it fails.

***Thanks to Oleg Vaskevich , Updated code with his points . 
And date range is 1-31 unlike month 0-11 
And Date(int,int,int) replaced with Date(long)***

edited code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day=cal.get(Calendar.DATE); // for dynamic reset rates


    callSince.setText("since(dd/mm/yyyy) :" + day + "/" + (month+1) + "/"  + year );
        // month+1 because month {0-11}

    Date resetDateDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());


    Calendar resetDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    resetDateCal.setTime(resetDateDate);
    String resetDate = String.valueOf(resetDateCal.getTimeInMillis());

    /*
     * CALL INCOMING
     */

    projection = new String[] {CallLog.Calls.DURATION };
    selection = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=? AND " + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " >=?" ;
    selectionArgs = new String[] { (String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE)) , (resetDate) };

    try
    {
        Cursor cIn = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        startManagingCursor(cIn);
```

Comment: I mean without that comparison I can retrieve some data , while with comparison i get none . NOTE : NO EXCEPTIONS RAISED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see here that subtracting 1 from January results in -1, not December. To resolve this, use the [`java.util.Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class's method `add()` to handle rolling over the proper fields. For example:

```
myCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Only after you're done working with the calendar can you retrieve the actual fields of the calendar.